# adventureworks 2005 and 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

does anyone know what the differences are between these two databases? the reason i ask is i am taking a sql class, and they are using 2008, however, since i have sql server 2005 installed i am unable to use adventureworks 2008. thank you for your help.

Comment: For the purposes of your class, I would definitely recommend installing SQL 2008 R2 Express -- you can run an instance side-by-side with 2005.  That way you will be working with the same thing as your co-students.

Comment: @guy i am unable to install it because it says NEED TO REMOVE SQL SERVER 2005 TOOLS when i try to install the 2008

Comment: That's cool uninstall the 2005 TOOLS because you will have the 2008 Tools with BOTH databases.

Comment: @capd how do i uninstall the tools?

Answer (score 5):

From the official site for [AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AW2008Details&referringTitle=Home):

> AdventureWorks 2008R2 Details
>
> The following changes have been made in the design of AdventureWorks2008 and AdventureWorks2008R2:
>
> - The way people and businesses are represented has changed. Some tables have been added, renamed, and deleted. These changes enable better integration with the Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework.
> - New data types and attributes are now demonstrated in the database including:
>
>   - date and time
>   - hierarchyid
>   - geography
>   - filestream
> - Integrated full-text support has been incorporated into the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
The following databases were designed for SQL Server 2005 but will also work just fine on SQL Server 2008 and higher.
AdventureWorks    -- the OLTP database
AdventureWorksDW  -- the Data warehouse
AdventureWorksLT -- a smaller, simplified subset ofj the AdventureWorks data

The following databases were updated for SQL Server 2008 and will NOT work with SQL Server 2005.
AdventureWorks 2008   -- the OLTP database
AdventureWorksDW2008  -- the Data warehouse
AdventureWorksLT2008  -- a smaller, simplified subset ofj the AdventureWorks data
```

source:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlserversamples/thread/1ece1f93-313d-46d0-97e6-c8ce24aa9cc5